# Changing the comments link produced by the get_comments_link() and get_comments_pagenum_link() functions

Tags: comments, links, pluggable, core

Currently my theme calls upon `get_comments_link()` to create the standard anchor **#comments** to link to the comments below the post, as does the `get_comments_pagenum_link()` function on paginated comments.

I would like to replace the **#comments** anchor in these functions with any other string, without of course changing WP's core php files.

A simple `add_filter` to completely replace core functions (other than in pluggable.php) doesn't seem to be possible. Are there any other ways of achieving this small change to the output of a core function, that use PHP (rather than say Java)? Is there a way here of using an `add_filter` with `str_replace()` perhaps?

This will be useful for foreign language sites, and for redirecting comments to another page with a url request, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution to the `get_comments_pagenum_link()` function is straightforward enough:

```
add_filter('get_comments_pagenum_link' , 'new_get_comments_pagenum_link');
function new_get_comments_pagenum_link($content) {
    $content = str_ireplace('#comments' , '#other', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Which filters the output of `get_comments_pagenum_link()` to replace **#content** with **#other**, or any other string you might choose.

For the `get_comments_link()` function, which can't be filtered, I have simply discovered that my WordPress theme uses it already within its own comments link function, and so have filtered this theme function instead, using the same method shown above.

Answer (score 1):

For the function `get_comments_link()` no such filter exists. You might want to use an alternative function called `get_comment_link()` which has a filter: `get_comment_link`.

For the function `get_comments_pagenum_link()` a filter exists: `get_comments_pagenum_link`.

To learn about how filters work please see [Plugin API (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). The information there should answer all question about how to use `add_filter()`.

As the link is a string in PHP, you can use any of the PHP string functions to locate, extract and replace stuff. [Full list of PHP String functions (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).